# Using case to change values in a table regardless of column

Tags: sql, null, case

I am currently querying a table that has some null values scattered around. Without having to specify each column (and without updating the actual data) is there a way that I can replace all null values with the word "BLANK"?

I had considered using CASE but it seems that you need to reference each column to make that happen

Comment: You can use the COALESE keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do what you are asking. This is best done in the application layer.

Answer (score 2):

COALESCE(columnName, "Blank") AS FirstNotNull

Comment: any way to do this for all columns without typing in the name of each column?

Answer (score 1):

no, the best way would be to use isnull, but unfortunately you have to do it on each column:

```
select isnull(your_field, "BLANK")
from your_table
```

Comment: I said "no" it cant be done. Just provided the best solution I think can be used